# JS Keycode is Safari mobile is the same

Tags: javascript, safari, keycode

I want to prevent user to type only numbers in an input field. Using javascript :

```
var shift_on = false;
$document.on('keydown', 'input[type="number"]', function(e) {
    var c = e.keyCode;
    if (c === KEYCODE.SHIFT)
        shift_on = true;

    //number using shift
    if ((shift_on || isMobile) && c >= 48 && c <= 57)
        return true;

    if (c >= KEYCODE.NB_ZERO && c <= KEYCODE.NB_NINE
            || c === KEYCODE.BACKSPACE
            || c === KEYCODE.DEL
            || c === KEYCODE.DOT
            || c === KEYCODE.COMMA
            || c === KEYCODE.ARROW_LEFT
            || c === KEYCODE.ARROW_RIGHT
            || c === KEYCODE.SHIFT
            || c === KEYCODE.CONTROL
            || c === KEYCODE.END
            || c === KEYCODE.HOME
            || c === KEYCODE.TAB
            )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
})
```

It works fine on PC but if you use Safari on a mobile, pressing "&" and "7" give the same keycode=55.

So how do I know the key pressing is "&" or "7" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`keyCode` does not mean the *character*.**

keyCode is the same for `7` and `&` for *all* borwsers, not just Safari, as they are the same physical key on a keyboard.
This is also why number row 7 (55) is a different key from numpad 7 (103).

If you think this model is outdated, you are right.  keyCode is [legacy](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#legacy-key-models) and [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

---

**`key` gives you the character.**

[event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) give you the character being typed.
It is standard, unlike keyCode and charCode, and it supports a lot more keys.
Even IE 9+ [support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key).
But with [Safari being the new IE](https://nolanlawson.com/2015/06/30/safari-is-the-new-ie/)...

```
var key = event.key || String.fromCharCode( event.charCode );
```

```js
document.querySelector( 'input' ).addEventListener( 'keypress', function( event ) {
   if ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey ) return; // Control shortcuts
   var key = event.key || String.fromCharCode( event.charCode ); // Safari & mobile Chrome
   if ( key.length !== 1 || key === '\x00' ) return; // Non-printable keys
   if ( key < '0' || key > '9' ) event.preventDefault(); // Stop non-numeric
});
```

```html
<input placeholder='Number only'>
```

That snippet works ok, after we manually allow keys like Arrows, Enter, or Ctrl+V.
It won't stop copy and paste or [IME input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method), though.
Can we do better?

---

**HTML5 has numeric and phone number input.**

Depending on your need, you can let HTML5 input handles it without writing any JavaScript.
It is as simple as [`<input type='number'>` or `<input type='tel'>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type).
The browser will switch to the correct keyboard type and prevent invalid input from being submitted.

```html
<input type='number' placeholder='integer'>
<input type='number' placeholder='float' step='2'>
<input type='tel'    placeholder='tel'>
```

Alternatively, you may use the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) for finer control, regardless of type.

Type / pattern is user friendly, cannot be bypassed by copy and paste or IME, is pretty future proof, and is very easy to maintain.
They are [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) by all modern browsers, including the venerable IE, so please use them if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `keypress` event (instead of `keydown`) as long-pressing keys on mobile keyboards often has special meaning. Alternatively, you might try checking charCode instead of keyCode to grab the actual character:

```
var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
```

or

```
var c = e.charCode;
```